# Drop Column from Large Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this largish table with three columns as such:

```
+-----+-----+----------+
| id1 | id2 | associd  |
+-----+-----+----------+
|   1 |  38 | 73157604 |
|   1 | 112 | 73157605 |
|   1 | 113 | 73157606 |
|   1 | 198 | 31936810 |
|   1 | 391 | 73157607 |
+-----+-----+----------+
```

This continues for 38m rows. The problem is I want to remove the 'associd' column but running `ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN associd;` simply takes too long. I wanted to do something like: `ALTER TABLE table_name SET UNUSED associd;` and `ALTER TABLE table_name DROP UNUSED COLUMNS CHECKPOINT 250;` then which apparently speeds up the process but [it isn't possible in MySQL?](http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/115428-solved-set-unused-column-for-mysql/)

Is there an alternative to remove this column-- maybe creating a new table with only the two columns or getting a drop with checkpoints?

Comment: I removed the sql-server tag because the question is explicitly about MySQL.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Anything that you do is going to require reading and writing 38m rows, so nothing is going to be real fast.  Probably the fastest method is to put the data into a new table:

```
create table newTable as
    select id1, id2
    from oldTable;
```

Or, if you want to be sure that you preserve types and indexes:

```
create table newTable like oldTable;

alter table newTable drop column assocId;

insert into newTable(id1, id2)
    select id1, id2
    from oldTable;
```

However, it is usually faster to drop all index on a table before loading a bunch of data and then recreate the indexes afterwards.

Comment: That took 17:09 minutes which is much faster than removing the column (which I stopped after three hours), I'm suprised but I appreciate the help!

Comment: Gordon, I wonder why copying two columns is faster than just dropping one row. Can you please tell me why ?

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev . . . Modifications to an existing table require a lot of overhead in terms of locking and locking parts of the table and logging all the changes.  Creating a new table is more optimized.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Thank you. Where can I get more information about this ? Is this a challenge is all rdbms or only mysql ?

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev . . . It is a problem in all databases and rather poorly documented.  The basic idea is really that the engine can recognize a "bulk insert" type operation but an update is really row-by-row (in a sense, although updates can be run in parallel).  A quick Google yielded this example on SQL Server:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlperf/archive/2007/02/16/high-volume-update-performance.aspx.

Comment: You have to remember the posible consequences for the `foreign keys`. They are not created in the `create table like` sentence, and if there is any external foreign key pointing to the oldTable I am not sure if they will be reconnected to the new table... Also you have, as a final step, to rename the new table to have the name of the old one.. at the same time you are deleting the old one.

Answer (score 12):

Disclaimer: this answer is MySQL oriented and might not work for other databases.

I think in the accepted answer there are some things missing, I have tried to expose here a generic sequence I use to do this kind of operations in a production environment, not only for adding/removing columns but also to add indexes for example.

We call it [the Indiana Jones' movement](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pr-8AP0To4k).

### Create a new table

A new table using the old one as template:

```
create table my_table_new like my_table;
```

### Remove the column in the new table

In the new table:

```
alter table my_table_new drop column column_to_delete;
```

### Add the foreign keys to the new table

The are not generate automatically in the `create table like` command.

You can check the actual foreign keys:

```
mysql> show create table my_table;
```

Then apply them to the new table:

```
alter table my_table_new
  add constraint my_table_fk_1 foreign key (field_1) references other_table_1 (id),
  add constraint my_table_fk_2 foreign key (field_2) references other_table_2 (id)
```

### Clone the table

Copy all fields but the one you want to delete.

I use a `where` sentence to be able to run this command many times if necessary.

As I suppose this is a production environment the `my_table` will have new records continuously so we have to keep synchronizing until we are capable to  do the name changing.

Also I have added a `limit` because if the table is too big and the indexes are too heavy making a one-shot clone can shut down the performance of your database. Plus, if in the middle of the process you want to cancel the operation it will must to rollback all the already done insertions which means your database won't be recovered instantly (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5654/internal-reason-for-killing-process-taking-up-long-time-in-mysql)

```
insert my_table_new select field_1, field_2, field_3 from my_table 
where id > ifnull((select max(id) from my_table_new), 0)
limit 100000;
```

As I was doing this several times I created a procedure: https://gist.github.com/fguillen/5abe87f922912709cd8b8a8a44553fe7

### Do the name changing

Be sure you run this commands inmediately after you have replicate the last records from your table. Idealy run all commands at once.

```
rename table my_table to my_table_3;
rename table my_table_new to my_table;
```

### Delete the old table

Be sure you have a back up before you do this ;)

```
drop table my_table_3
```

Disclaimer: I am not sure what will happen with foreign keys that were pointing to the old table.

Comment: Thank you for this! 

I had troubles doing online DDL changes on several very large (50 million records) tables on a MySQL 5.5 server which does not yet support ALGORITHM=INPLACE.

Foreign keys pointing to the old table should be dropped before doing that and recreated after the rename. This will also take some time.

RENAME TABLE is atomic so this is a true online DDL change.

Comment: A small addition from 2022 to an already great answer. MySQL 8 (maybe some older versions too) supports renaming multiple tables with one statement: `RENAME TABLE tbl TO tbl_old, tbl_new TO tbl;`.

Comment: Would be nice to hear how to handle the foreign keys which are still pointing to the old table. Should we recreate all of the foreign keys? That might take more time than dropping the column itself if table is interconnected a lot with others.

Answer (score 2):

You can speed up the process by temporarily turning off unique checks and foreign key checks. You can also change the algorithm that gets used.

```
SET unique_checks=0;
SET foreign_key_checks=0;
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN column_name, algorithm=inplace;
SET unique_checks=1;
SET foreign_key_checks=1;
```

Using the above code, it took my PC about 2 minutes to drop a column from a 20 million row table.

If you're using a program like Workbench, then you may want to increase the default timeout period in your settings before starting the operation.

If you find that the operation is hanging indefinitely, then you may need to look through the list of processes and kill whatever process has a lock on the table. You can do that using these commands:

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
KILL PROCESS_NUMBER_GOES_HERE;
```

Comment: Was this with InnoDB or MyISAM?

Comment: @user1111929 - InnoDB

Answer (score 1):

The best solution in this case in `MySQL` is to:

1) change the table `Engine` to `MyISAM`

2) change whatever you want to do (Drop column, alter data type,etc..)

3) change it back to `InnoDB`

In this case the DBMS will not be locking/unlocking at each record iteration.

However note that this solution would be good if you have several things you want to change in your table/database, because once you revert it back to `InnoDB`, this will take the same amount of time to drop one column.
So only consider this solution if you have multiple things to change in your database.