# Which is less disruptive: multiple small alter table queries or one big one

Tags: mysql

```sql
ALTER TABLE tbl DROP COLUMN col1, ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE;
ALTER TABLE tbl DROP COLUMN col2, ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE;
ALTER TABLE tbl DROP COLUMN col3, ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE;
```

vs

```sql
ALTER TABLE tbl 
DROP COLUMN col1, col2, col3, 
ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE;
```

I have a very large table (millions of records) that I need to remove some columns from. The table is used extensively by most endpoints.

I'd like to drop these columns with minimal impact on API response times.

Which approach is likely to cause the least disruption?

For example, maybe the single queries will cause more total table lock time, but each lock might be shorter, and if I space them out, it will be less disruptive to the API.

Comment: @RaymondNijland you are right.. this approach would not work if the Table is being actively written as well.

Comment: @RaymondNijland check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41121989/2469308

Comment: i removed mine other comments @MadhurBhaiya but that last link is also a bad suggestion.. As it assumes MySQL is using a default order as `LIMIT` is used there without deterministic sort which "pagination" or better said batch processing always requires..

Comment: This question might be more suitable for https://dba.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Did you consider creating a new table and copying the desired columns into that one?

Comment: *"Did you consider creating a new table and copying the desired columns into that one? "* How would that work.. @SalmanA the main table seams to be extensively used .. How would you prevent a data state change (added/change/deleted records) before the copy and rename is done without a lock on the live table..

Comment: @RaymondNijland a [question on dba.se](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/250094/160363) brought me to this tool for large table online schema changes: https://github.com/github/gh-ost It handles things about a table being heavily active etc

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya that tool only works when [binairy log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-log.html) is enabled, which most likely is only active (read enabled) when the server is running replication..  But it seams ok from what i read assuming it can also totally run locally and import on one MySQL server...